# Itunes top albums JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json, itunes

How can I get Itunes top albums name, artist name & id JSON to PHP.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json
```

I tried something like

```
<?php
$content=file_get_contents("https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json"); 
$top_albums=json_decode($content);
$tracks = $top_albums->feed->entry;
foreach( $tracks as $track ) {
$name = $track->title->lable;
echo $name. "<br/>";
}
?>

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$lable in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\itunes.php on line 6
```

need working code to get all albums from feed->entry like im:name im:artist im:image title.

Comment: can you `print_r($top_albums)` to see what it has?

Comment: yes it output array like stdClass Object ( [feed] => stdClass Object ( [author] => stdClass Object ( [name] => stdClass Object ( [label] => iTunes Store ) [uri] => stdClass Object ( [label] => http://www.apple.com/itunes/ ) ) [entry] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [im:name] => stdClass Object ( [label] => The Very Best of Prince )

Comment: can you `print_r($track)` in `foreach` loop

Comment: yes like stdClass Object ( [im:name] => stdClass Object ( [label] => The Very Best of Prince ) [im:image] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [label] => http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music3/v4/aa/78/73/aa787325-b7ff-1e4a-e2ca-58cc61d4fe5b/dj.sotjrlll.jpg/55x55bb-85.jpg [attributes] => stdClass Object ( [height] => 55 ) )

Comment: try to access $track->label i think it will work

Comment: Error: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$lable in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\itunes.php on line 6

Comment: try to access $track['label']

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\itunes.php on line 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the object properties with special characters, you will need to escape them:

```
$image = $track->{'im:image'}[0]->label;
echo $image . '<br />';
```

The braces allow you to access the property with the :, the square brackets allow you to access the array index number.

There's also a typo on line 6 throwing the error, lable should be label:

```
$name = $track->title->label;
```

Comment: Thanks alot everything is fine now. main issue was special chars in properties resolved by using braces.